# Using a Cloud Function to Update a Firebase Realtime Database Reference to Add Data

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm registering a customer, uploading their stripeID, uid, and e-mail to my Firebase Realtime Database, and then uploading their profile image to Firebase Storage. However, I'm wondering if I need an update Cloud Function to add the full name, username, and profile image to the customer reference? Or do I need to refactor my AuthService function? If I do need an update function, how do I access the constants for the three information details for my Cloud Function? Thank you.

**Cloud Functions**

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

    const email = data.email
    const uid = context.auth.uid
  
    if (uid === null) {
      console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt')
    }
  
    return stripe.customers.create({
       email : email
    }).then( customer => {
      return customer["id"]
    }).then( customerId => {
      admin.database().ref("customers").child(uid).set(
        {
          stripeId: customerId,
          email: email,
          id: uid
        }
      )
    }).catch( err => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create Stripe customer.')
    })
  
})

exports.updateCustomer = functions.database.ref("customers/{id}").onUpdate( (change, context) => {

    

})
```

**AuthService**

```
struct CustomerCredentials {
    let email: String
    let password: String
    let fullname: String
    let username: String
    let profileImage: UIImage
}

static func createCustomer(credentials: CustomerCredentials, completion: @escaping(DatabaseCompletion)) {
        
        guard let imageData = credentials.profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = CUSTOMER_PROFILE_IMAGES.child(filename)
        
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { meta, error in
            storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                guard let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: credentials.email, password: credentials.password) { result, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard let uid = result?.user.uid else { return }
                    
                    let values = ["email" : credentials.email,
                                  "uid" : uid,
                                  "fullname" : credentials.fullname,
                                  "username" : credentials.username,
                                  "profileImageUrl" : profileImageUrl]
                    
                    REF_CUSTOMERS.child(uid).setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: completion)
                }
            }
        }
        
}
```

**Register Function**

```
@objc func handleCreateAccount() {
        
        guard let profileImage = profileImage else {
            self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Please select a profile image.")
            return
        }
        
        guard let fullname = fullnameTextField.text , fullname.isNotEmpty ,
            let username = usernameTextField.text?.lowercased() , username.isNotEmpty ,
            let email = emailTextField.text?.lowercased() , email.isNotEmpty ,
            let password = passwordTextField.text , password.isNotEmpty ,
            let confirmPassword = confirmPasswordTextField.text , confirmPassword.isNotEmpty else {
                self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Please fill out all fields.")
                return
        }
        
        if password != confirmPassword {
            simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Passwords do not match, please try again.")
        }
        
        showLoader(true, withText: "Registering Account")
        
        let credentials = CustomerCredentials(email: email, password: password, fullname: fullname,
                                              username: username, profileImage: profileImage)
        
        AuthService.createCustomer(credentials: credentials) { error, ref in
            if let error = error {
                Auth.auth().handleFireAuthError(error: error, vc: self)
                self.showLoader(false)
                return
            }
            
            Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeCustomer").call(["email" : email]) { result, error in
                if let error = error {
                    Auth.auth().handleFireAuthError(error: error, vc: self)
                    self.showLoader(false)
                    return
                }
            }
            
            self.showLoader(false)
            guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else { return }
            guard let tab = window.rootViewController as? MainTabController else { return }
            tab.setupNavigationControllers()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
}
```

**Database Reference**

[image]

Comment: If you are using `Auth.auth()` to create an account, where do they sign in?

Comment: They sign in on the login controller using `Auth.auth().signIn`

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what's the problem here, are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @Barraguesh, I'm having trouble with getting the full name, username, and profile image to save to my reference. It's like my cloud function is canceling everything in my AuthService function out.

Comment: Have checked the logs for what might be rejecting it? I would recommend checking what the reply of the affected functions are to see what the server is saying, if things are not working, an error has to exist somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope I understood what you meant.

You don't need Cloud Function to add and update some user's personal information. I think you should store user's personal information in Firestore Database.

The user is already registered. The userUID exists because the user is logged in. Create a collection in Firestore Database and make the collection name the userUID of the user. Create documents under Collection and save the user's personal information in them. In this way, each user can update their personal information. The important point here is that you have to set the accesses from Rules. Another user should not access someone else's information.

[image]

Data writing, reading and updating codes can be found in the Firebase documentation.

If you use Firestore Database, the user can delete, add and update their information according to the code you wrote. If you want to change user information, I suggest you to search Firebase Admin.

If I misunderstood or you think there is missing information, please let me know in the comment.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I'm having trouble because I'm using a cloud function to assign a stripeID to the customer. So my full name, username or profile image is not being assigned